# HTML chat on mobile phone: Keep divs in place

Tags: html, css

I am having a chat web application:

```
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="header-bar"></div>
  <div id="chat-messages"></div>
  <div id="input-form></div>
</div>
```

How can I make it that:

a) the id=viewport is always 100% visible screen (even with disappearing/appearing bottom bar at safari mobile)

b) id=header-bar stays on top

c) id=input-form stays at bottom

I have tried all combination of div structures (width/height and position) and had no success. Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Do I need JS/JQ for this?

Comment: Include your code!

Comment: One thing at a time. Your question is too broad. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand from the question (providing some more code could help), you might mean something like this.

```css
#header-bar {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background-color:#ccc;
overflow:hidden;
padding:.5rem;
z-index:1;
}
#input-form {
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background-color:#ccc;
padding:.5rem;
z-index:1;
}
#viewport {
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:flex;
}
#chat-messages {
width:100%;
height:80%;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
transform: translateY(2%);
z-index:0;
}
#chat-messages p {
width:100%;
height:20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="header-bar">header</div>
  <div id="chat-messages"><p>message 1</p><p>message 2</p><p>message 3</p><p>message 4</p><p>message 5</p><p>message 6</p><p>message 7</p><p>message 8</p><p>message 9</p><p>message 10</p><p>message 11</p><p>message 12</p><p>message 13</p><p>message 14</p><p>message 15</p><p>message 16</p><p>message 17</p></div>
  <div id="input-form"><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
</div>
```